# Is this example right? Neural network

Tags: pattern-matching, neural-network

I am reading a book about neural networks because I am really interested in AI. But I came across this neural network example in the book. They want to show you the usefulness of neural networks. They want the neuron to recognize the pattern as shown in the upper box. Then they say the output will be only 1 when the threshold is 1,5 and the inputs are the same as the upper box so: i1 = 1, i2 = 0, i3 = 1 and i4 = 0.

[image: Neural network example]

But lets say all the numbers in the box are 1, then the output will be 2 also. And then it will return true when that pattern isn't the same as the upper box. I am really new to neural networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way they designed the weights, if you observe, any pattern that has `i1 = 1, i4 = 1` will be recognized by the network because the weights are 1, 1 for these inputs and 0s for others. 
If you want just that pattern `i1 = 1, i2 = 0, i3 = 0, i4 = 1`then the weights should be learnt in such a way, for example if `w1 = 1, w2 =-1, w3 = -1 , w4 = 1,`and threshold be `>= 1` not `1.5` then - only `i1 = 1, i2 = 0, i3 = 0, i4 = 1` is recognized all other patterns are not recognized.